# Iphone, how do I fix this warning: '-respondsToSelector:' not found in protocol(s)

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, iphone-sdk-3.0

I'm getting this warning.

'-respondsToSelector:' not found in protocol(s)

It occurs on the line marked by "HERE" below.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
    titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    id<SetsSectionController> sectionController = 
        [sectionControllers objectAtIndex:section];

    if ([sectionController respondsToSelector:
            @selector(tableView:titleForFooterInSection:)]) { //HERE

        return [sectionController tableView:tableView 
            titleForFooterInSection:section];

    }
    return nil;
}
```

Heres my full h files.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface SettingsTableViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSArray *sectionControllers;

}

@end
```

What do i need to do to fix the error?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Either make `SetsSectionController` inherit from `NSObject`:

```
@protocol SetsSectionController <NSObject>
```

...or cast to `id`:

```
if ([(id) sectionController respondsTo...])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ([(NSObject *)sectionController respondsToSelector:
        @selector(tableView:titleForFooterInSection:)])
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone needed,

```
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"tableView:titleForFooterInSection:");

if([sectionController respondsToSelector:selector]) {
    objc_msgSend(sectionController, selector, tableview, section);
}
```

Note: Don't forget this, `#import <objc/message.h>`